# AndroidStudio ConstrainLayout not working

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-studio-3.4

I am beginner in android studio and having headache with this if someone could help me am i missing something?.... I have problem with Constraint layout, the problem is i put some element(ImageView, Button it does not mater) in layout and constraint it to parent but when I run it in emulator it just is not showing. also it is not showing me those buttons under elements connect BaseLine and remove Constrains for that element.

"screenShot": [image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout        
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="343dp"
        android:layout_height="118dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_c`enter code here`onstraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic[7]" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The attribute `tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic[7]"` is only valid for design and not runtime. Use `app:srcCompat=...`

Comment: thanks, i fixed that problem, can you help me out With missing conect to base line button in design tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.it's difrent in new Android Studio 3.4, You have to Right click on element and option Show Base Line is there now.

Answer (score 0):

> when i run it in emulator it just is not showing

The problem is here :

```
tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic[7]"
```

You need to understand what [`tools`](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes) is, so I recommend to you to read a little bit the documentation.

Just a note of it :

> It's a namespace that enable design-time features (such as which layout to show in a fragment) or compile-time behaviors (such as which shrinking mode to apply to your XML resources). When you build your app, the build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK size or runtime behavior.

Instead you have to use to show it on the emulator.

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_drawable"
```

*Note: remember to add : `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`*

Comment: Thanks on fast answer. I fixed that part , but why is not showing me conect base line on UI elements? it works normal in xml but no in design tab?

Comment: Can you upload the project on github and send me the link?